# SQL Update Query help

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table called Subject_table.. I'm trying to update a field in that table.... but i keep getting a syntax error.... Not sure wad i'm doing wrong. All fields in the table are of type VARCHAR(30)

This is what the queryString looks like

```
queryString2 = "update "+tablename+" set tittle='"+tittle+"' , desc='"+desc+"', creditPoints='"+creditPoints+"' where cid='"+cid+"'";
```

Actual query

```
UPDATE subject_table 
SET tittle='Subject 1', desc='Subject 1', creditPoints='5' 
WHERE cid='CSE11111';
```

I also have delete query which works fine...

Would appreciate the help..!!!
The table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dummy`.`subject_table`;
CREATE TABLE  `dummy`.`subject_table` (
  `cid` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `tittle` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `desc` varchar(550) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `creditPoints` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Are you sure that `desc` is not recognized as a reserver word? Maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: Could you please post the exact error message? And it is really called "tittle" with 2 "t"?

Comment: can you show us table definition please?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc='Project B', creditPoints='5' where cid='CSE3PRB'' at line 1

Comment: Exactly what I've already pointed out in my comment and answer: `desc` is a reserved word... :)

Comment: In your delete query you use quoted _desc_, here it is why that's correct

Comment: Thanks... I did this

UPDATE subject_table s
SET s.tittle='Subject 1', s.desc='Subject 1', s.creditPoints='5' 
WHERE s.cid='CSE11111';

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that `desc` is not recognized as a reserved word?
Maybe I'm wrong...

Try this:

```
UPDATE subject_table 
SET tittle='Subject 1', `desc`='Subject 1', creditPoints='5' 
WHERE cid='CSE11111';
```

In your delete query you use quoted `desc`...

Answer (score 0):

Should be `where cid='CSE11111'`, and `desc` maybe the reserved keyword of your database, try to quote it by **`**.

Answer (score 0):

"desc" is a keyword. Try putting that within square brackets like this:

```
update subject_table set tittle='Subject 1' , [desc]='Subject 1', creditPoints='5' where cid=('CSE11111');
```

Comment: Wrong quotes for MySQL (but we only just learned that this was a MySQL question), you'd want backticks for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error might be coming from the column name "desc".

Try escaping this column, as well as removing the brackets from the where clause.

```
update subject_table set tittle='Subject 1' , [desc]='Subject 1', creditPoints='5' where cid=('CSE11111');
```